# How to reverse a String converting int to String?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type the integer you'd like to be reversed:");

        int num = s.nextInt();
        String strNum = ""+num;
        reverse(s1);
        System.out.println(reverse(s1));
    }

    public static int reverse(int strNum) {

        String s1 = Integer.toString(strNum);
        for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
              System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward - I want to reverse my input of numbers, but I am unable to.

There are errors at '`reverse(s1);`' and '`System.out.println(reverse(s1));`' , as `s1` is not recognized. I cannot figure out the cause.

Comment: `s1` variable is in `reverse` method and not in `main`. Use `strNum` instead

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`; use a `char[]` array; ... also `s1` should probably be `strNum` when calling `reverse`

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not compile as is. `s1` is not in main method and `reverse` method is accepting an `int` not `String`. 
Also, if you need to return an `int` from your method why not the reversed `int` which is the answer.

Few edits to your code which will solve your issue.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type the integer you'd like to be reversed:");

    int num = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(reverse(num));
}


public static int reverse(int num) {
    String strNum = String.valueOf(num);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=strNum.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        sb.append(strNum.charAt(i));

    return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any variable s1
you assigned value of string number to 'strNum', So use it instead
Also you have to use string as argument type in definition of reverse()

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type the integer you'd like to be reversed:");

        int num = s.nextInt();
        String strNum = ""+num;
        reverse(s1);
        System.out.println(reverse(s1));
    }

    public static int reverse(String strNum) {

        for(int i=strNum.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
              System.out.print(strNum.charAt(i));
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type the integer you'd like to be reversed:");

    int num = s.nextInt();
    String strNum = ""+num;
    reverse(strNum);
}

public static int reverse(String strNum) {

    String s1 =strNum;
    for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
          System.out.print(s1.charAt(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder("your string");
String result = sb.reverse().toString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ===============try the below code===============================
public static void main(String sr[])
{
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Type the integer you'd like to be reversed:");

     int num = s.nextInt();
     String strNum = ""+num;
     String inputString = String.valueOf(num);
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(inputString);
     System.out.println(builder.reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use stack , below is a simple implementation of reversing a string    by using stack. You can easily change the code for Integer, The complexity is O(n) which is good i think.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    String retVal = "";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {

        String nextStr = String.valueOf(s.nextInt());

        for (int i = 0; i < nextStr.length(); i++) {
            stack.push(String.valueOf(nextStr.charAt(i)));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nextStr.length(); i++) {
            retVal+=stack.pop();
        }

        System.out.println(retVal);
    } finally {
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the integer you'd like to be reversed:");
        int num = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(num)).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

we can use stringBuffer or StringBuilder for reversing